# Javascript check form onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html

I've used `event.preventDefault()` to stop the `form` action and call the `login()` , but when the `login` function return `true`, it still can't do the form action?

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();return login();" action="index.php" method="get" id="register-form" >
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function login() {

    var password = window.prompt("Please input password", "");
    if (password !== '123') {
        alert('Password is incorrect');
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Success');
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Kindly accept the answer, if your problem is solved, if not add the comments on the answer

Answer (score 4):

Remove `event.preventDefault();` from the `onsubmit`. This will stop the form submission regardless of the value returned from `login()`.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/nt8sd3zh/)

```js
function login() {

  var password = window.prompt("Please input password", "");
  if (password !== '123') {
    alert('Password is incorrect');
    return false;
  } else {
    alert('Success');
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return login();" action="index.php" method="get" id="register-form">
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```